# JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final and Log4j-extras

Tags: jboss

I want to add log4j-extras jar in my jboss server but i don't know how to do this correctly.

I put apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar into jboss_HOME/modules\org\apache\log4j\main (same location as log4j-1.2.16.jar) and my module.xml looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.apache.log4j">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
        <resource-root path="apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.dom4j" optional="true"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logmanager"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.modules"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

After start jboss, i have new files in the directory :
 apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar.index and log4j-1.2.16.jar.index

I have an application which use an external log4j.properties.
 The configuration is ok but when i try to add  "log4j.appender.test=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender", i have the error message  "log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender]"

So i guess that the add of log4j-extras is not ok.

Can someone tell me the correct configuration to do in jboss ? (maybe the module.xml is not  correct or i need to create an other directory in module ?)
 Thanks a lot !